# Why does W-DAY behave confusingly in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The behaviour of `freq = "W-SUN"` etc. seems confusing and inconsistent. For example, `d.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2019-07-09'), pd.Timestamp('2019-11-11'), freq='W-SUN')` produces a sequence of Sundays, but `pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('2019-07-09')]).to_period('W-SUN').to_timestamp()` produces a Monday. What is going on here?

This has come up because I have an index of dates that I want to round to some frequency, while also generating a `date_range` with the same frequency and phase. It seems like `index.to_period(freq).to_timestamp()` and `pd.date_range(start, end, freq=freq)` should work for this, but it doesn't when freq is `"W-DAY"`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a little counter-intuitive, but here's the logic.  When you use `.to_period()`, Pandas calculates the period of time within which the date you supplied falls.  The way Pandas calculates this period is to find the next day that matches your specified frequency and extending the period backwards to include your chosen day.  In other words, **the period is end-inclusive, not start-inclusive**.

To find the Sunday-anchored week for a given Tuesday, it finds the *next Sunday* after that Tuesday and adds the previous six days.  When you convert to timestamp, however, *it selects the first day of that period*, which in this case will be a Monday. If you asked for the Sunday-anchored period of a Sunday, it would give you that day plus the previous six days, not the following six days.

If you want your period to start rather than end on a particular day of the week, just set the frequency string to the day prior.  In your case, `pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('2019-07-09')]).to_period('W-SAT').to_timestamp()` should do the trick.

---

Some hopefully helpful demonstrations:

`pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('2019-07-09')]).to_period('W-SUN')` gives:

```
PeriodIndex(['2019-07-08/2019-07-14'], dtype='period[W-SUN]', freq='W-SUN
```

Note that this period *ends on* a Sunday.  When you run `pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('2019-07-09')]).to_period('W-SUN').to_timestamp()` it gives you the first day of this period:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-07-08'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

You can observe how the days are chosen by running:

```
for f in ['W-SUN', 'W-MON', 'W-TUE', 'W-WED', 'W-THU', 'W-FRI', 'W-SAT']:
    print(f, pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('2019-07-09')]).to_period(f))
```

Which gives:

```
PeriodIndex(['2019-07-08/2019-07-14'], dtype='period[W-SUN]', freq='W-SUN')
PeriodIndex(['2019-07-09/2019-07-15'], dtype='period[W-MON]', freq='W-MON')
PeriodIndex(['2019-07-03/2019-07-09'], dtype='period[W-TUE]', freq='W-TUE')
PeriodIndex(['2019-07-04/2019-07-10'], dtype='period[W-WED]', freq='W-WED')
PeriodIndex(['2019-07-05/2019-07-11'], dtype='period[W-THU]', freq='W-THU')
PeriodIndex(['2019-07-06/2019-07-12'], dtype='period[W-FRI]', freq='W-FRI')
PeriodIndex(['2019-07-07/2019-07-13'], dtype='period[W-SAT]', freq='W-SAT')
```

Note that the start of the chosen period jumps in the middle, but the logic remains consistent.

Comment: Sure. I guess the inconsistency I'm talking about is the way to_period and to_timestamp coerce to the end of the week whereas date_range coerces to the start. Obviously I could deal with that in this instance by manually offsetting one freq to get the same behaviour, but I'd ideally like a general method that works for a range of frequencies (e.g. also month and day).

Comment: Agreed - it seems inconsistent between methods, if not within each method.  Even if there's a good reason for `to_period` to work this way, perhaps a feature request to add an argument that would flip the behavior would be in order?  That would have the nice side effect of making the behavior clearer in the documentation.